# PHP - covert nodeValue of dom document to string or array?

Tags: php

I want to convert the text in the table from html file to string and add them to the array but ...

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('table.html');
$table=$doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$s=$table->item(0)->nodeValue;
echo $s; // it's ok , i got string .
$arr=explode(' ', $s); //i add string to array but..
echo "<br>";
echo count($arr); //why this string when explode to array has 1917 element??
echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);  // and it has many space element ??
echo "</pre>";
```

How do I remove space between the elements in the array? Is there any other way to do this?
i want array number from string ,like this : 
    $arr[0]=1.85 ,
    $arr[1]=1.84,
    $arr[2]=1.75 ,
.....
...

This is table.html file :
https://app.box.com/s/1rwuk6daujgkxrwg4z4b

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: what do you want in $arr ?

Comment: Edit question and provide sample input and expected output. Otherwise question is unclear. Voting to close.

Comment: i want array number from string ,like this : $arr[0]=1.85 ,$arr[1]=1.84,$arr[2]=1.75 ,.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if You  need anchor tag value from only first table then Try this:

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('s.html');
$table=$doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$tableDom = $table->item(0);
foreach($tableDom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $t)
{
    if(is_numeric($t->nodeValue))
    {
        $result[]= $t->nodeValue;
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1.85 [1] => 1.84 [2] => 1.75 [3] => 1.74 [4] => 2.05 [5] => 2.09 [6] => 2.21 [7] => 2.25 )
```

**Option2**
If you need all numeric value from your string then try this:

```
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('table.html');
$table=$doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
$s=$table->item(0)->nodeValue;

$arr[]=$s; //i add string to array but..
preg_match_all('/(([\+|\-]{1})?\d(.{1})?)+/', $arr[0], $matches);
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $matches[0]);
echo "</pre>";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Array ( [0] => -0.25 [1] => 1.85 [2] => 1.84 [3] => 1.75 [4] => 1.74 [5] => 2.05 [6] => 2.09 [7] => 2.21 [8] => 2.25 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing it wrong , you need to loop through the anchor tag and discard the non-numeric characters....

```
<?php
$doc=new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('table.html');
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $tag)
{
    if(is_numeric($tag->nodeValue))
    {
    $arr[]= $tag->nodeValue;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.85
    [1] => 1.84
    [2] => 1.75
    [3] => 1.74
    [4] => 2.05
    [5] => 2.09
    [6] => 2.21
    [7] => 2.25
)
```